# update logging level before start of the application

Tags: python, logging

Before starting my web application using `uvicorn.run(app, host=settings.HOST, port=settings.PORT)` I instantiate logging like this

```
logging.config.dictConfig(
    {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "filters": {
            "throttle_elastic_failures": {"()": "de.core.log.filters.ThrottleElasticFailures"},
            "ignore_etcd_retries": {"()": "de.core.log.filters.IgnoreMaxEtcdRetries"},
        },
        "root": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["console"]},  # default is INFO
        "formatters": {"default": {"format": formatters.DEFAULT_FORMAT }},
        "handlers": {
            "console": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "formatter": "default",
                "filters": ["ignore_etcd_retries"],
            },
        },
        "loggers": {},
    }
)
```

Then I read the settings files

```
# configure env
env_settings = settings_vial.Settings(env_prefix="DE_")
env_settings.load_env()
env_settings.load_dotenv_file(env_settings.ENVFILES_SECRETS)
locals().update(env_settings._config)
settings.configure(env_settings)
```

I want to change the root level of logger using the parameter from the settings. I used to do it like this

```
logging.config.dictConfig(
    {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "filters": {
            "throttle_elastic_failures": {"()": "de.core.log.filters.ThrottleElasticFailures"},
            "ignore_etcd_retries": {"()": "de.core.log.filters.IgnoreMaxEtcdRetries"},
        },
        "root": {"level": settings.LOG_LEVEL, "handlers": ["console"]},  # default is INFO
        "formatters": {"default": {"format": formatters.DEFAULT_FORMAT }},
        "handlers": {
            "console": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "formatter": "default",
                "filters": ["ignore_etcd_retries"],
            },
        },
        "loggers": {},
    }
)
```

I was basically resetting `dictConfig` again. Is there a way just to change the logging level? Because everything else stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(settings.LOG_LEVEL)
```

to set the root logger level *after* you've called `dictConfig()`, if the level is all that's changing.